# Django Migration ran without error, but database is not changed

Tags: django, django-migrations

I merged two tables into one on April 13, 2018.

```
Migrations for 'caseAT':
caseAT/migrations/0004_auto_20180413_1802.py
- Remove field case_ptr from papoose
- Add field lead to case
- Add field neighbor1 to case
- Add field neighbor2 to case
- Add field page_to_paragraph to case
- Add field pagerange_int_range to case
- Add field paranum_array to case
- Add field quills to case
- Add field root to case
- Delete model Papoose
(aishah) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/aishah/jamf35$ git commit -m 'just adding the migration I just did for the streamlined/consolidated case papoose merge.'
[post_repair_diff_and_align a3fbb69] just adding the migration I just did for the streamlined/consolidated case papoose merge.
1 file changed, 69 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 caseAT/migrations/0004_auto_20180413_1802.py
```

Then I took a break from this project to work on something else. Today, when I went back to this project, I got an error and looked to find that although my migration file and my models were as I expected them to be, the database was not. I ran showmigrations and this particular one, 0004_auto_20180413_1802.py, did not have a check in the box. I ran makemigrations and got "No changes detected" but when I ran runserver I got:

```
You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): caseAT.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

So of course I ran the migration, and got this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "case_ptr_id" of relation "caseAT_papoose" does not exist
```

You will note that this column, and the entire table, were supposedly removed on April 13. WTF is going on here, and how do I fix it? Thanks.

ps: I know that the whole point of the orm is to not muck around in the db, but in this case, would I be better off manually changing the db table to match my model?

Comment: `- Remove field case_ptr from papoose`.  seems like you have removed that.

Comment: add `case_ptr` as foreignkey and migrate the changes.

Comment: Did you maybe run some migration (or reverse migration) using the `--fake` flag? If the database is in the correct state, you can run `migrate --fake` to add entries to the database to show that the migrations have been applied.